# java Swing: How to pass value by pressing one button while other button is already pressed

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project with Java swing and Matlab. I have a GUI with 2 buttons "Run" and "Pause". I am using one more java program (Matlabjavaprog.java) where I am running a loop as follows:

```
int pause = 0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    if (pause == 20000) {
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(pause); 
            System.out.println("Now delayed for 20s!");
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {} 
    } else {
        proxy.setVariable("n", i);
        proxy.eval("n=n+1");
        proxy.feval("myfun");
    }
}
```

When I pressed "Run" button, the else part executes. But I want to press "Pause" button in between this loop where value of pause (20000) will be passed to java program from GUI, and the execution should be delayed by 20000ms. However, I am not able to press "Pause" button until "Run" is executing the loop.

"Run" button:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Run");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pauseButton.setEnabled(true);
                prog1.main(args); // a java program that calls another program Matlabjavaprog.java (which calls an instance of Matlab)
                }
        });
```

"Pause" button:

```
pauseButton = new JButton("Pause");
        pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int p =20000;
                Matlabjavaprog.getpause(p); // a function in Matlabjavaprog java program that passes pause value from GUI to this program
            }
        });
```

Actually "Run" creates a TCP connection with MATLAB and within it it runs several instances of data set. The whole process cannot be put in thread as it will not allow to reconnect as it has already a connection. It seems that once I pressed "Run", I cannot press "Pause" until run is complete. Is there any way to execute "Pause" button that could delay the loop as per user need? Currently, I am not able to sent pause value to the running program, i.e., Matlabjavaprog.java. Any help will be appreciable!

Comment: No, your problem looks to be one of concurrency in that you're running long-running code on the Swing event thread. To solve this, you shouldn't be running a second class's main method as you're doing ,but instead should create OOP-compliant classes, create instances, call instance methods **in a background thread** and give the 2nd program a mechanism, a method that allows other code to pause it.

Comment: You'll also not want to leave that InterruptedException catch block empty, if this is going to work.

Comment: Logic of "Run" is the first priority. Actually it is doing many things, I cannot change it (passes different parameters to different functions in different java programs and then call Matlab to run Matlab script). I can make easy change for the logic of "Pause" button.

Comment: `"I cannot change it (passes different parameters to different functions in different java programs and then call Matlab to run Matlab script). I can make easy change for the logic of "Pause" button."` -- you are going to **have to change it**, at the very least by making sure that your Matlab code is run in a background thread. Without doing this, you can try to make all the changes to pause that you want, but it won't solve your problem.

Comment: Actually "Run" creates a TCP connection with MATLAB and within it it runs several instances of data set. The whole process cannot be put in thread as it will not allow to reconnect as it has already a connection.

Comment: And actually, I'm betting that it can. You've not mentioned anything above that would disallow this.

Comment: Can you give an example code to support your view? I did not understand it completely how to achieve what you have mentioned.

Comment: Please have a look: [SwingWorker examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+swingworker)

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the execution in another thread by implementing [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and using an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html)

e.g.

```
AtomicBoolean isPaused = new AtomicBoolean(false);
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
       while(true){
       if(isPaused.get()){
         Thread.sleep(20000);
         isPaused.set(false);
       }
       proxy.setVariable("n", i);
       proxy.eval("n=n+1");
       proxy.feval("myfun");
      }
   }
}).start()
```

Then in your pause button, call a setter that calls isPause.set(true) and that should make it clickable. It's a start anyway - I like using atomics for signaling between threads for simplicity.

Comment: looking at your question more closely, maybe you could just put prog1.main(args); in the thread. There's a lot of ways to solve this and they all involve concurrency.